# I just need to center an unordered list, and image in the middle of a blank page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to center just 2 elements in the center of a page. This is a page with clickable icons for your social links. But I need to find a way to center them in a way that they are centered no matter the device's size. Please bare in mind this is my second day ever developing. Any feedback is highly appreciated!

[Here is what it should look like in the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thw7v.png)

Here is the code I have

```
<div class="fresh">
    <img width="160" src=logo.svg>
</div>

<div class="icons-inline">
    <ul class="icons">
        <a href="https://www.hypeunit.co" class="hype"><svg>insert super long svg</svg></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/Fresheys" class="twitter"><svg>insert super long svg</svg></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCjD9wyRBMV9hqC2snDGqEUA" class="youtube"><svg>insert super long svg</svg></a>
        <a href="https://twitch.tv/fresheys" class="twitch"><svg>insert super long svg</svg></a>
        <a href="https://discord.com/invite/ez6YhCs" class="discord"><svg>insert super long svg</svg></a>
        <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@fresheys?" class="tiktok"><svg>insert super long svg</svg></a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com/fresheys" class="instagram"><svg>insert super long svg</svg></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### css:

```
.fresh {
    color: #E3EEF8;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20%;
}

.icons {
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 1.5%;
}
```

I'm currently just using text-align and then setting the padding to 20% on the top text so that it pushes both of them down and appears centered only on MY specific screen. But I want it to work on phones, other monitors, etc.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, only `<li>` elements are allowed as direct children of `<ul>` elements

Answer (score 1):

use flex-box, try this:

You can skip the `* {...}` since it will override every element in your document, and you'll have to set margin and padding manually

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap; /* can also try column wrap */
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#main-container{ /* this will be the size of your browser window */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

html:

```
<section class="flex-container" id="main-container">
   <!-- your things here -->
</section>
```

if you want an `ul` to show `li` elementos horizontally just add `flex-container` class to it, it will show horizontally, then you can add this rule `ul.flex-container li` to treat those kind of list better, e. g:

```
ul.flex-container li{
    margin: 15px 0 0 15px;
}
```

your code could look like this:

```
<section class="flex-container" id="main-container">
    <ul class="flex-container">
        <li>Element 1</li>
        <li>Element 2</li>
        <li>Element 3</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

you'll have a main container with the size of fhe window with its elements centered, inside youll have a list with its elements horizontally aligned

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this approach:

```css
.pageContainer {
   display: grid;
   place-items: center;
   min-height: 100vh;
}
```

You can read more about it directly from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items

Comment: Thank you! How could I make the ul horizontal again though? When I do that it becomes vertical.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question at first sight, just edited it. Basically you need to add a container (with a class="pageContainer") to the whole page, this container will centralize anything inside it.
Welcome to the community

Comment: It's getting closer! Now it is sort of squeezing everything together, and it put the last icon on another line. I think this is because of the "display: grid?"  

image: https://gyazo.com/2c51e98f6dfc0e2a3c211333a48e81bf

Answer (score 0):

**Create a container at least as big as the screen, and align the content to the center of the container.**

The centering of elements can be handled by [Flexbox](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). You just need to make sure that the container that holds the logo and the list of social media icons is as big as any screen the user might have. You can use [viewport-percentage sizes](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) for that, for example `min-height: 100vh` means “make the height of this element at least 100 percent of the viewport height”, where viewport is the size of the browser window.

Here’s a working solution:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/280/120" alt="Logo" />
  <ul>
    <li>Icon 1</li>
    <li>Icon 2</li>
    <li>Icon 3</li>
    <li>Icon 4</li>
    <li>Icon 5</li>
    <li>Icon 6</li>
    <li>Icon 7</li>
  </ul>
</main>
```